# Broadcast Receiver Listener

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am having broadcast listener which will listen outgoing call made by the user and shows what is the duration and how much time it takes to connect.
So for the broadcast listener i did it using below approaches

```
<receiver android:name=".service.CallReceiveBroadcast" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml**

and another is register/unregister broadcastlistener programmatically

```
registerReceiver(callReceiveBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL));
unregisterReceiver(callReceiveBroadcast);
```

My question is

1. Which one is good approach(Can be applicable for all other broadcast listener).
2. Which method consumes more battery(if in case it consumes!! :)).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is better because this way the code becomes reuseable. Because every developer that ever works with your code can just look in the manifest what intent filters are being used. If you do that programmatically you'll need to put alot of comments around it to make sure people read it.

And the battery problem isn't going to make a big difference so I would just choose the one you prefer.

Comment: Yes. you are right. First approach is better. As in second approach you need to register and unregister receiver. That makes it bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

My answers to your questions would be:

1. The best approach is the one you need.

   **a)** If you need to be registered to those 2 actions all the time then, adding the receiver in the Manifest file is the good option here.

   **b)** If you want to listen to those two messages only when the user opens a specific Activity for example then you should go for the second option as you can simply register and unregister when you need to.
2. The battery life isn't affected by just registering to an action but it is affected by what you are doing in `onReceive`.. so if you are doing something heavy(and you shouldn't) in `onReceive` then when you use the manifest registration your onReceive method will get caught a lot more than when you are registering for the event only when you need to. But that depends on what you want to achieve.